# How to restrict to one method call at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'd like to know how to implement the following restriction: One method in my Windows Service should not be called again before the earlier call has been finished. The method in question goes thru couple of database tables and it's very important that this process won't be called again before it's finished.  I have a setting that defines how often my service will activate and under normal circumstances it never activates before the earlier call has been finished (because whole process should not take more than couple of minutes and the interval is set to 10 minutes) but thats not sure enough. I guess.

How to implement this?

Comment: Do you want subsequent calls to be skipped, or queued?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a [named Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(VS.80).aspx) or a [named Semaphor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(VS.80).aspx)e to ensure that only one holder of the Mutex/Semaphore is executing at once. As a commenter pointed out, keep in mind you must be careful not to abandon a mutex or improperly acquire/release a semaphore.

Comment: I'd rather use a named semaphore, no risk of getting an abandoned mutex then so no need to have to deal with the additional possibility of experiencing the exception or having to think about ownership.

Comment: +1 Peter Morris, I'll add a blurb about the possibility of a named Semaphore, however, they too have problems with improper releasing, etc

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to use locking:

```
private readonly object myLock = new object();

private void MyMethod()
{
   lock(myLock)
   {
      //code goes here
   }
}
```

This ensures that this method can never be running more that once at a time.

Comment: don't forget to make myLock static - the question actually implies multythreaded situation.

Comment: I believe it is actually a multi-process situation.

Comment: Will it stop calls or run them afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

I second the Mutex suggestion, but you might also want to take a look at transactions. Wrap your entire code in a transaction (this requires a `using System.Transactions`):

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try 
    {
        /* ... your current code here */
        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        /* Any appropriate error handling/logging here */
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

A transactionscope automatically locks all related tables. You can reduce the restrictions and allow other processes to read, but not write to the data that your process is touching. You do this by passing options to the TransactionsScope constructor.

Comment: Odd, all of that message didn't get sent to me the first time, bug in the system?

Comment: Glitch in my typing. I accidentaly submitted my reply before finishing the complete post.

Comment: A transaction alone cannot be used to synchronize code. It can only be used to *consistently* access data.  How tables are locked, or if at all, depends on the isolation-level of the transaction.  That is totally different than using a mutex (things like SQL*Server's sp_get_applock() set aside).

Answer (score 1):

Well if all the code is localized you can set a boolean and check the boolean before executing the method, otherwise you can IPC and request the state before execution.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

1. You can put a check in the call to check some flag or call Monitor.TryEnter and return with an error/do nothing if negative.
2. You can queue up calls (if you need this method to execute more than once) and only invoke when Monitor has been signaled.
3. If you don't mind blocking, and the method is on a separate thread, you can join the thread of the method you want to wait.

I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind restricting one thread at a time to the entire object, then you can use:

[Synchronization Contexts](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization_Contexts)

1. Have your class inherit from **ContextBoundObject**
2. Apply a **[Synchronization]** attribute to the class.

The CLR will only allow one thread at a time to execute code per instance of this class.  The others will block until the lock is released by the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your function run with await/async

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim yourLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); //allow only 1 thread at time

...
private async Task<string> YourFunction() { 
await yourLock.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                //your code go here
            }
            finally
            {
                yourLock.Release();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a serial workflow... Have you considered using a workflow framework?